# What is for Python what 'explode' is for PHP?

Tags: php, python, string

I had a string which is stored in a variable `myvar = "Rajasekar SP"`. I want to split it with delimiter like we do using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in PHP.

What is the equivalent in Python?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Choose one you need:

```
>>> s = "Rajasekar SP  def"
>>> s.split(' ')
['Rajasekar', 'SP', '', 'def']
>>> s.split()
['Rajasekar', 'SP', 'def']
>>> s.partition(' ')
('Rajasekar', ' ', 'SP  def')
```

[`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)

Answer (score 17):

The alternative for explode in php is [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

The first parameter is the delimiter, the second parameter the maximum number splits. The parts are returned without the delimiter present (except possibly the last part). When the delimiter is None, all whitespace is matched. This is the default.

```
>>> "Rajasekar SP".split()
['Rajasekar', 'SP']

>>> "Rajasekar SP".split('a',2)
['R','j','sekar SP']
```