# Pass variable from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python

I am trying to pass the value of a variable from php to a python script.

php:

```
<?php 
$item = array('warren');
$command = escapeshellcmd('hello.py $item');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
input = sys.argv[1]
print input
```

This results in `$item` displayed. I've tried all manner of different quotation marks, but still can't get the actual value (`warren`) to be passed.  How do I get the value stored in $item to get passed, not the literal?
I've also tried [How to pass variable from PHP to Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197815/how-to-pass-variable-from-php-to-python)

Php:

```
<?php                                            
$item = array('warren');                                                  
$output = shell_exec('hello.py' . $item);
echo $output;
?>
```

But this gives me error:

`Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\crud\clientdetails.php on line 613`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable from PHP to Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197815/how-to-pass-variable-from-php-to-python)

Comment: I have tried this too, see edit

Comment: What is line 613?

Comment: `$output = shell_exec('hello.py' . $item);`

Comment: `$output = shell_exec('hello.py ' . $item[0])`

Comment: Just do everything in python...

Answer (score 1):

You can do either,

```
$output = shell_exec('hello.py ' . implode(',', $item));
```

Then [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854867/what-is-for-python-what-explode-is-for-php) the string in Python or you could pass only value in the array,

```
$output = shell_exec('hello.py ' . $item[0])
```

**Reading Material**

[`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because you are trying to pass an array as a string.

If you want to pass the data in $item. You would need to do:

```
$string;
foreach ($item as &$value)
{
  $string .= $value . ",";
}
$output = shell_exec('hello.py' . $string);
```

Turns the $item array into a string which can then be passed into your python