# Passing variables: php >> python and then python >> php

Tags: php, python, selenium

I want to pass the variable from php to python and i use this code for that:

php

```
<?php

    $item='http://www.google.com';
    $tmp  = passthru("python test.py ".$item);
```

python

```
from selenium import webdriver
import sys
link = sys.argv[1]
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get(link)
s = driver.page_source
```

and this works fine, but now in this process, I want to pass this variable s from python in the PHP, can I do it somehow in one step, when I pass the variable from PHP to python to receive the result of python code again in the PHP

Comment: try using `shell_exec`, using `shell_exec` run your python script which returns a `json`, this will get stored in your `shell_exec` var. Won't this work?

Comment: $tmp = shell_exec('python test.py ' . $item);

Comment: this does not work

Comment: this does not work because your python script is not giving any output

Comment: so what should i add?

Comment: This isn't new, there are many questions like this in SO.. here is one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201954/pass-variable-from-php-to-python)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
from selenium import webdriver
....# your code here
print(driver.page_source)
```

in PHP

```
$tmp = shell_exec('python test.py ' . $item);
```

Now your `$tmp` should have `driver.page_source` value

Comment: i dont know why, but this dont works for me, shell_exec does not works, only passthru

Comment: @dssada what's your python version?