# Python syntax to parse variable

Tags: python-3.x

I was parsing a XML file using python, I got a variable assigned with below values

```
server = `sys:var1=value1,var2=value2,var3=value3`
```

can some one please assist me how can I parse this variable 'server' now. I want to fetch the individual values like

```
var1 = value1
var2 = value2
var3 = value3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is for Python what 'explode' is for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854867/what-is-for-python-what-explode-is-for-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Python's regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to parse any string. for your requirement bellow code will give you list of variables(`valiables`) and corresponding value(`values`) in a list.

```
import re

server = 'sys:var1=value1,var2=value2,var3=value3'
variables = re.findall(r'([\w]+)=', server)
values = re.findall(r'=([\w]+)', server)
```

**Result**

> variables: ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
>   values: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

**Brief Explanation**
in the above code 
`([\w]+)=`: finds one or more alpha-numeric and underscore( _ ) characters followed by `=`.
`[\w]+`: means select one or more alpha-numeric and underscore( _ ) characters
`(...)`: groups those selected character and leaves behind `=` in result
You can refer bove link for more details about `regex` expression.

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking tick mark. And you can read more about regex for better manipulation.